# Sending Discord messages from external module without using events

Tags: discord.py

I intend to use a Django web application where users of the application will be able to send messages to Discord.

The idea is that this message will be sent through a Discord bot instead of webhooks so that I am able to add reactions to the messages and easily manage the message.

Is it possible to achieve this functionality using the discord.py library?

Upon researching the discord.py documentation, it seems that messages are sent as a result of certain events that occur in Discord.

Comment: Can you include example code? And to clarify, is your question how to send messages to an arbitrary channel?

Comment: I don't really know what kind of code to include as my question is more of an application architecture question. I want to be able to send a message to an arbitrary Discord channel, but only when instructed to do so by the Django web application.